# Detect unmappable characters in stream

Tags: java

I'm writing a stream of characters to a text file in a single-byte encoding.
I'd like to be able to detect unmappable characters in the stream to take a fallback action (which is high-level and does not drop or replace invalid characters).

I'm using OutputStreamWriter now, but how can I be sure it will throw on mapping failure?

```
private void convert(Iterable<String> lines, OutputStream os) throws CoreException, IOException {
    String lineDelimiter = ResourcesUtils.getLineDelimiter(file.getProject());
    Charset charset = Charset.forName(file.getCharset());
    CharsetEncoder encoder = charset.newEncoder();
    encoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);
    try (OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(os, encoder)) {
        Joiner.on(lineDelimiter).appendTo(writer, lines);
    }
}
```

This code throws on sample invalid input, but it is unclear if it is guaranteed to do so on other implementations of OutputStreamWriter or inputs.

What is a robust way to get an exception when converting a stream with unmappable characters?

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened when you fed it invalid data?

Comment: It worked fine with me - not using **Guava's Joiner** though. Maybe that is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to construct OutputStreamWriter with various constructors and tested if it will throw on ummappable input on write attempt.

Generic test case looked like:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Writer writer = createWriter(outputStream);
writer.write("ホク");
writer.close();
```

With following `createWriter()` implementations:

- `new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "windows-1251")` - does not throw
- `new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, Charset.forName("windows-1251"))` - does not throw
- Configured encoder:

  CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName("windows-1251").newEncoder();
  encoder.onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.IGNORE);
  new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, encoder);

  does not throw
- `new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, Charset.forName("windows-1251").newEncoder())` - does throw

This behavior is a bit surprising and [is not specified](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html). 
Moreover documentation says:

> This class always replaces malformed surrogate elements and unmappable
>   character sequences with the charset's default substitution sequence.
>   The CharsetEncoder class should be used when more control over the
>   encoding process is required.

Which contradicts with last experiment results.

Tested on Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15) (linux)

OutputStreamWriter in general does will not throw on mapping failures, but sometimes it does. I'll still use it because raw CharsetEncoder API is not stream-suitable, but welcome more robust solutions.